# Fancybox: How to dissolve between images?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fade

When I switch between images in a gallery using fancybox, one image is fading out and then the next one is fading in. Between those two transitions there is nothing shown. Thus it seems to "flash". I.e: One image is shown > click next > image fades out > blank page (very briefly) > next image fades in.

What I'd like to achieve is a "dissolve" effect. I want to fade one image ABOVE the other. So that there is always one image shown. I.e: One image is shown > click next > next image fades on top of previous one.

How do I do this?